# Process.Start throwing an win32 exception for Combobox list

Tags: c#, process.start

Below is a code I've been working with for about two weeks now and thought I had it working till I put in the last information (Class MyClient) and now I'm getting a win32 error at the Process.Start(url);
Says the specified file cannot be found. I've tried setting it to "iexplorer.exe" to have it load IE for the URL, but no change.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyClient> clients;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clients = new List<MyClient>();
        clients.Add(new MyClient { ClientName = "Client 1", UrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com" });
        BindBigClientsList();
    }

    private void BindBigClientsList()
    {
        BigClientsList.DataSource = clients;
        BigClientsList.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
        BigClientsList.ValueMember = "UrlAddress";
    }

    private void BigClientsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClient c = BigClientsList.SelectedItem as MyClient;
        if (c != null)
        {
            string url = c.ClientName;
            Process.Start("iexplorer.exe",url);
        }
    }
}
class MyClient
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string UrlAddress { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `ClientName` as the URL, which is not correct...

```
string url = c.ClientName;
```

...should be...

```
string url = c.UrlAddress;
```

You shouldn't specify `iexplorer.exe` either. By default, OS's open URLs with the default web browser. Unless you really need your users using Internet Explorer, I suggest letting the system pick the browser for you.

**UPDATE**
*In respose to OP's comment...*

It depends on what you mean by "blank". If you mean `null`, no this is not possible. Using `null` as the first entry in your list will result in a NullReferenceException when you try to call `c.UrlAddress`. You might be able to use a place-holder `MyClient` instance with dummy values...

```
clients = new List<MyClient>();
clients.Add(new MyClient { ClientName = "", UrlAddress = null });
clients.Add(new MyClient { ClientName = "Client 1", UrlAddress = @"http://www.google.com" });
```

But then you would have to change your action method to something like this...

```
private void BigClientsList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClient c = BigClientsList.SelectedItem as MyClient;
    if (c != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.UrlAddress))
    {
        string url = c.ClientName;
        Process.Start("iexplorer.exe",url);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something different if they select a list item without a Client instance or URL
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I was overlooking a simple mistake like that

Comment: On a side note, do you believe it is possible based on the code above to insert a blank for the first combobox entry so it doesn't autoload the URL?

Comment: @user1666884 - Please see update to my answer.